# Rename PHP array key and maintain element data

Tags: php, arrays, key, rename, unset

I am trying to uniformly rename all of my array keys using a foreach loop and unset.

Array before:﻿

```
Array 
(   [0] => Array ( 
        [store_nl] => Store One 
        [id_nl] => 123456 
        [title_nl] => Product One 
        [price_nl] => $9.00 ) 

    [1] => Array ( 

        [store_ds] => Store Two 
        [id_ds] => 789012 
        [title_ds] => Product Two
        [price_ds] => $8.00 ) 
)
```

foreach using unset:

```
if(isset($data)){
    foreach ( $data as $k=>$v )
    {
    //Store One (ds)
      $data[$k]['Store'] = $data[$k]['store_ds'];
      $data[$k]['ItemID'] = $data[$k]['id_ds'];
      $data[$k]['Description'] = $data[$k]['title_ds'];
      $data[$k]['Price'] = $data[$k]['price_ds'];
      unset($data[$k]['store_ds']);
      unset($data[$k]['id_ds']);
      unset($data[$k]['title_ds']);
      unset($data[$k]['price_ds']);
    //Store Two (nl)
      $data[$k]['Store'] = $data[$k]['store_nl'];
      $data[$k]['ItemID'] = $data[$k]['id_nl'];
      $data[$k]['Description'] = $data[$k]['title_nl'];
      $data[$k]['Price'] = $data[$k]['price_nl'];
      unset($data[$k]['store_nl']);
      unset($data[$k]['id_nl']);
      unset($data[$k]['title_nl']);
      unset($data[$k]['price_nl']);
    }
}
```

Array after:

```
Array 
(   [0] => Array ( 
        [Store] => Store One 
        [ItemID] => 123456 
        [Description] => Product One 
        [Price] => $9.00 ) 

    [1] => Array ( 
        [Store] => 
        [ItemID] => 
        [Description] => 
        [Price] => ) 
)
```

All of the array keys have been changed, but some of the data is now gone? Can someone please tell me a better way to do this without data loss?

Comment: "rename all of my array keys using a foreach loop and unset." --- just create a complretely **new** array instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do what you deed:

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
        'store_ni' => 'Store One',
        'id_ni' => 123456,
        'title_ni' => 'Product One',
        'price_ni' => '$9.00'
    ),
    array(
        'store_ds' => 'Store Two',
        'id_ds' => 789012,
        'title_ds' => 'Product Two',
        'price_ds' => '$8.00'
    )
);    


$newKeys = array('Store', 'ItemID', 'Description', 'Price');    

$result = array();
foreach($myArray as $innerArray)
{
    $result[] = array_combine(
        $newKeys,
        array_values($innerArray)
    );
}
```

array_combine() combines the first array you pass to it and assign it as the keys of the returned array and the second array you pass it as the values of that array.

Comment: You didn't look carefully at the OP's input array. The keys in the first sub-array end in `_nl` and the keys in the second sub-array end in `_ds`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, he wants all of the keys in the initial array(s) to be changed to same keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_flip()` to flip between the keys and values, then it'll be easy to run over the values and "flip" the array again (back to its original state). It should be something like:

```
$tmp_arr = array_flip($arr);
$fixed_arr = array();
foreach($tmp_arr as $k => $v){
    if($val == "store_nl"){
        $fixed_arr[$k] = "Store";
    }
    // etc...
}
// and now flip back:
$arr = array_flip($fixed_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays should have the same number of elements, but I think that's the case here.

```
$data = [[
  'store_nl' => 'Store One',
  'id_nl' => 123456,
  'title_nl' => 'Product One',
  'price_nl' => '$9.00'
], [
  'store_ds' => 'Store Two',
  'id_ds' => 789012,
  'title_ds' => 'Product Two',
  'price_ds' => '$8.00'
]];
$keys = ['Store', 'ItemID', 'Description', 'Price'];
$data = [
  'nl' => array_combine($keys, $data[0]),
  'ds' => array_combine($keys, $data[1])
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive php rename keys function:

```
function replaceKeys($oldKey, $newKey, array $input){
    $return = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if ($key===$oldKey)
            $key = $newKey;

        if (is_array($value))
            $value = replaceKeys( $oldKey, $newKey, $value);

        $return[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $return;
}
```